# Graphics Card not working - Dead in BIOS - Error Code 43 on Windows

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, motherboard, bios

After pixel errors showing up on the whole screen resulting in a blue screen, the graphics card seemed to be dead. When I reboot my computer the BIOS screen appears in very bad resolution with many pixel errors (when monitor is plugged in into the graphics card). Windows 10 then boots up in a 800x600 resolution (using Microsoft Basic Display Driver), again with constant pixel errors all over the screen. When I open the device manager, it detects the graphics card (Asus GTX 670 Direct CU II), but with the error Code 43. My first thought was that my graphics card is dead, so I just used the iGPU (Intel HD Graphics 4000 on i7 3770k), until I can buy a new card. Said and done everything worked fine with the iGPU. I then bought a new MSI GTX 1660 Gaming X, plugged it in and everything is the same like before with the GTX 670. Pixel errors, Windows error 43 etc. I then swiped the drivers and reinstalled them, reinstalled Windows, flashed the BIOS, nothing worked. Since the problem already appears on BIOS level, it must be a mainboard related problem?! I already tried other PCIe slots on my mainboard (Gigabyte ZA-77 DS3h), but nothing worked either. When i use tools like AIDA64 I see the whole specs of the graphics card, meaning its detected fine, but somehow disabled. Windows troubleshoot also detected the problem with the card but didn't solve it. Everything else (RAM, SSD, HDD, CPU, network card) works fine.

Is there anything that I missed or that I can do?

Comment: Does your motherboard have built in VGA?

Comment: @JohnnyVegas Yes, you can plug in VGA directly into the motherboard. Allthough I use HDMI and DVI at the moment

Comment: You already started nice and systematic diagnostics. Next steps would including rechecking the power supply (mainly those PSU to graphics cards cables. You swapped cards so I assume they are ok but if broken en delivering unsuffient power the cards will also malfunction) and trying on an other motherboard.

Comment: @Hennes you seem to have a point. I will buy a new PSU tomorrow and test it with that. The thing is that now (suddenly?) when I have the graphics card (new or old doesn't matter) plugged in I get a BIOS error message (as beep tones) which says that there is an error with the graphics card (1x long beep, 3x short beep). Weirdly also my new (and stronger) wifi network adapter doesn't find any wifi signals anymore, but with the old one everything works fine. I don't know if that relates in any way to the other problem, but its weird too

Answer (score 0):

Connect to inbuilt vga without the external video card plugged in - If all appears ok then try using another slot - If the problem reappears your external card has reached the end of it's life.

Comment: I used HDMI and DVI to connect to the motherboard (without the graphics card plugged in) and everything worked fine. But as I said i also bought a new graphics card and both the old and new didnt work but were detected by Windows, so its rather unlikely that they are both dead no?

Comment: Both ports on the video card will be affected as they both go through the same video chip which has the issue. Using onboard VGA is to double check that it isn't a monitor or cable which is at fault

Comment: So onboard DVI or HDMI doesn't count? Because both of them work (with the graphics card taken out of the system)

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise that you had those on your motherboard - Those are just as an effective test